# Reset while loop conditions in python to "play the quiz again"

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm still new at this. Essentially, I just need the code to reset the while loop.

When the user reaches the end of the quiz, it asks if the user would like to play again. If the user inputs a `y` the quiz should restart.

My code:

```
print("Moose Quiz")

question = 0    # Tells us which questions the user has completed
questions = ["What is the average life span of a moose?: ",
             "How much do moose eat on a daily basis?: ",
             "The fastest moose ran...?: "]

userAnswers = ["","",""] # Stores the users answers

answers = ["a. 10 - 14 years\nb. 15 - 25 years\nc. Blue\nd. 26 - 35  years\n",
           "a. 24 lbs a day\nb. 39 lbs a day\nc. 67 lbs a day\nd. 73 lbs a day",
           "a. 20 mph\nb. 25 mph\nc. 35 mph\nd. 40 mph"]

correct = 0

while question < 3:
   print(questions[question])
   print(answers[question])
   answers[question] = input("To answer, pick a letter or leave it blank to skip it: ").lower()

   if question == 0:
       if answers[question] == "a":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "b":
           print()
           print("Good Job! That is correct.")
           correct = correct + 1
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "c":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "d":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "":
           print("Awww...you skipped one!")
           question = question + 1
           print()    
       else:
           print("Invalid character, please try again.")    

   elif question == 1:
       if answers[question] == "a":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "b":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "c":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "d":
           print()
           print("Terrific! You got it right!")
           correct = correct + 1
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "":
           print("Awww...you skipped one!")
           question = question + 1
           print()    
       else:
           print("Invalid character, please try again.")

   elif question == 2:
       if answers[question] == "a":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "b":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()        
       elif answers[question] == "c":
           print()
           print("Amazing! You're awesome!")
           correct = correct + 1
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "d":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "":
           print("Awww...you skipped one!")
           question = question + 1
           print()
           print("Thanks for playing!")
       again = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
```

Comment: Sorry if I got the formatting wrong, I'm still new at this. Essentially, I just need the code to reset the while loop. Everything I have tried has not been successful. Thanks for the help...

Comment: No problem, I've just fixed it. But maybe [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33447809/edit) and explain what's wrong and what's the expect output is a good idea.

Comment: When the user reaches the end of the quiz, it asks if the user would like to play again. If the user inputs a "y" the quiz should restart.

Comment: You're using `answers[question] = input("To an...`, but answers is a `list`. Do you mean that use a `dict` here? or covert the input to `int`?

Comment: Well, it's a multiple choice quiz. What I've tried to do is give the program a list of answers to pull from. That part of the quiz works fine. I just can't get it to reset the conditions to zero and restart the quiz.

Comment: And there is lots of duplicate code, you could define a function here. Or  try something like `elif answers[question] in "acd"`, `elif answers[question] == 'a' or 'c' or 'd'`, etc.

Comment: So you mean that your code can works, but it can't restart? You could use another `while` loop here.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, for your thoughts. I will take another look with your suggestions and revisit this another time.

Comment: Also the following :  `answers[question] = input(...]` will override your preset answers. You should probably use the `userAnswers` variable that you created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, you can reset question to 0

```
while question < 3:
   ...

   again = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
   if again == 'y': 
       question = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

just need to add another while loop

```
again = 'y'

while again == 'y':
   while question < 3:
   print(questions[question])
   print(answers[question])
   answers[question] = input("To answer, pick a letter or leave it blank to skip it: ").lower()

   if question == 0:
       if answers[question] == "a":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "b":
           print()
           print("Good Job! That is correct.")
           correct = correct + 1
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "c":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "d":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "":
           print("Awww...you skipped one!")
           question = question + 1
           print()    
       else:
           print("Invalid character, please try again.")    

   elif question == 1:
       if answers[question] == "a":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "b":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "c":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "d":
           print()
           print("Terrific! You got it right!")
           correct = correct + 1
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "":
           print("Awww...you skipped one!")
           question = question + 1
           print()    
       else:
           print("Invalid character, please try again.")

   elif question == 2:
       if answers[question] == "a":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "b":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()        
       elif answers[question] == "c":
           print()
           print("Amazing! You're awesome!")
           correct = correct + 1
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "d":
           print()
           print("Sorry, please try again.")
           question = question + 1
           print()
       elif answers[question] == "":
           print("Awww...you skipped one!")
           question = question + 1
           print()
           print("Thanks for playing!")

       again = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this answers[question] = input("To answer pick ...") will overwrite your answers list. So it is better to take the input in a separate variable

Second, To reduce the amount of code you could save your answers in a dictionary ('correct_answers' in the code below) and check the answer for every question

Third, To repeat the quiz you can just reset the question to 0

```
print("Moose Quiz")

question = 0    # Tells us which questions the user has completed
questions = ["What is the average life span of a moose?: ",
         "How much do moose eat on a daily basis?: ",
         "The fastest moose ran...?: "]

userAnswers = ["","",""] # Stores the users answers

answers = ["a. 10 - 14 years\nb. 15 - 25 years\nc. Blue\nd. 26 - 35  years\n",
       "a. 24 lbs a day\nb. 39 lbs a day\nc. 67 lbs a day\nd. 73 lbs a day",
       "a. 20 mph\nb. 25 mph\nc. 35 mph\nd. 40 mph"]

correct_answers = {0:'b',
               1:'d',
               2:'c'}
correct = 0

while question < 3:
    print(questions[question])
    print(answers[question])
    answer = input("To answer, pick a letter or leave it blank to skip it: ").lower()

    if answer == correct_answers[question]:
        print ()
        print ("Awesome")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif answer == "":
        print("Awww...you skipped one!")
        print()    

    else:
        print ()
        print ("Sorry wrong answer")
    question = question + 1
    if question == 3:
        again = input("Would you like to play again?: y or n")
        if again == 'y':
            question = 0
            correct = 0
```

Comment: Thank you to all for your help. Now I can see where I went wrong. Happy coding!